# Extract number from string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, function, debugging, parsing

I fail to extract a (double) number from a pre-defined input String using a regular expression.
The String is:

```
String inputline ="Neuer Kontostand";"+2.117,68";
```

For successfully parsing just the number I need to suppress the leading `+` while keeping an optional `-`. In addition I must cut off the `"` before/after the number.

Of course I could do multi-step string-operations, but does anyone know how to do all in a more elegant way using one regular expression?

What I tried so far:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-{0,1}[0-9.,]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputline);
String substring =m.group();
```

Comment: surround the part you want to extract as group with brackets ([0-9.,]*)

Comment: 1. `{0,1}` can be written as `?`; 2. your regex will match many things that are not numbers (e.g. `-` or `...` or even the blank string).

Answer (score 4):

```
Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?")
```

Explanation

```
-?        # an optional minus sign
[0-9]+    # decimal digits, at least one
(?:       # begin non-capturing group
  ,       #   the decimal point (German format)
  [0-9]+  #   decimal digits, at least one
)         # end non-capturing group, make optional
```

Note that this expression makes the decimal part (after the comma) optional, but does not match inputs like `-,01`.

If your expected input *always* has both parts (before and after the comma) you can use a simpler expression.

```
Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+,[0-9]+")
```

Comment: That's better, but doesn't address the problem that the OP is not *using*  the regex anywhere :)

Comment: @Tim That's... well. Not part of the question. ;)

Comment: Well, not really. The OP only stated that he failed to extract the number correctly. His regex *would*  have worked (somewhat), but he never used it. So that's his actual problem.

Comment: @Tim With respect to the mind-boggling abundance of Java regex usage examples I'd say mentioning this fact is more than enough.

Comment: Thanks! This was very fast and my regex now works fine. I only expanded the first group in your solution to [0-9.] to include the grouping separator (German format). My key problem in all my many tries was to use the star-sign instead of the plus-sign after the [0-9]. Thanks very much!

Comment: @user: If you want to make sure that only three digit groupings are accepted and the dot cannot be at the beginning, you can use use `"(?<![.,])\\b[0-9]{1,3}+(?:.[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]+)?\\b"`. I leave figuring that expression out as an exercise to you. :) It contains a few advanced concepts that worth figuring out. Also see http://fiddle.re/xkcg6, click the "Java" button.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NumRegEx {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String inputline = "\"Neuer Kontostand\";\"+2.117,68\"";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*;\"(\\+|-)?([0-9.,]+).*");
      Matcher m = p.matcher( inputline );
      if( m.matches()) { // required
         String sign  = m.group( 1 );
         String value = m.group( 2 );
         System.out.println( sign );
         System.out.println( value );
      }

   }
}
```

Output:

```
+
2.117,68
```

Comment: Still won't work: The `+` is unescaped (syntax error) and should be removed anyway.